# How to define the size (dimension) of an agent on a conveyor

Tags: anylogic

I am quite new with Anylogic.
I am trying to model a simple conveyor system.
I would like my conveyor to accumulate until the conveyed objects touch each other.

I have set the "gap" parameter of the conveyor to zero, but the objects accumulate with a pitch of (apparently) one meter ?
Am I missing something ?

Please have a look to the model:
https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/3af9fc14-8677-4171-9191-52614703bef6?mode=SETTINGS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the size of your agents in several places. Best one for you is likely in the `Source`block when you create your object agents. Tick the "change dimension" tickbox as below:

[image]

In your conveyor, you can override/adjust the length again if you like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. The source trick did the job.

For my own information: I m using convey, not conveyor. Is there a way to adjust the agent length in convey ?

Comment: Not sure. Please mark this as answered, though. Makes it easier for others to find it in the future.

Comment: If you do it at the source, the dimensions don't change anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom agent, you can set it to type Material Item (1).  You can then set the dimensions at the class level (2), and AnyLogic gives you this nice visual aid to see how big your item is (3).  This visual is nice, because then you can draw your shapes for animation purposes to match the size.

[image]

This approach would be for components that do not change in size, like pallets or consistent parts in a manufacturing environment.  For material items that have varying sizes, like boxes in a DC, I would probably use the source solution Ben suggested.